# What's the difference between the classes Floating and Fractional in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, fractions

What is the difference is between the `Floating` and `Fractional` classes in Haskell?

Comment: They're right next to each other in the Prelude.

Comment: What do you want to say exactly?

Comment: Is there really no info on the docs?

Comment: No more information is needed for this question.

Comment: Docs are indeed very poor

Comment: Potential close voters: this question is *definitely* not unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definitions of `Fractional` and `Floating` can be found in the documentation of the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional):

> ```
> class Num a => Fractional a where
>     (/) :: a -> a -> a
>     recip :: a -> a
>     fromRational :: Rational -> a
> ```
>
> Fractional numbers, supporting real division.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> class Fractional a => Floating a where
>     pi :: a
>     exp :: a -> a
>     log :: a -> a
>     sqrt :: a -> a
>     (**) :: a -> a -> a
>     logBase :: a -> a -> a
>     sin :: a -> a
>     cos :: a -> a
>     tan :: a -> a
>     asin :: a -> a
>     acos :: a -> a
>     atan :: a -> a
>     sinh :: a -> a
>     cosh :: a -> a
>     tanh :: a -> a
>     asinh :: a -> a
>     acosh :: a -> a
>     atanh :: a -> a
> ```
>
> Trigonometric and hyperbolic functions and related functions.
>
> [...]

So to translate that into English: A `Fractional` is any kind of number for which I can define a division:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

That can for instance be the case for *floating point* numbers, but also for *fractions* (where a fraction has a *numerator* and *denominator*). This is not the case for `Int` because if dividing an `Int` by an `Int` does not always produce an `Int` (well technically floating point division on a computer is not exact, but that is another story).

A subset of `Fractional` numbers are `Floating` numbers where trigonometric are defined. It is for instance impossible that the `sin` of a fraction always produces a fraction: a `sin` is defined as an sum over an infinite sequence. Only for a very limited number of cases (like `sin 0`) it holds. Basically the only numbers on a computer for which trigonometric are defined (approximatively) are floating point numbers.

Answer (score 12):

Very roughly:

- `Fractional` is the class of types that can represent (exactly or at least in a decent approximation) any [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number). It may ad lib also be able to represent other numbers, but that's not important.
  In other terms, it's just the class of number types that have a division operation; since it's a subclass of `Num` it follows from this that the types must contain the rational numbers.
- `Floating` is the class of number types that are closed under limits in the Cauchy sense, i.e. [complete spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space). This is necessary to do any sort of calculus. The methods of the `Floating` class are functions that are mathematically defined as limits, namely infinite sums (which are the limits of the sequence of partial sums of taylor series).
  Since you can define the real numbers as limits of sequences of rational numbers and because again `Floating` is a subclass of `Fractional`, any `Floating` type is able to represent (again, at least *to a decent approximation*) any [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

A good way to visualise the difference is through topology: `Floating` types are [connected spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), i.e. they form a continuum. What this means for floating point numbers is: every value is understood as a whole *interval* of real numbers (because floating-point always has some uncertainty). When you lay these intervals side by side, you tile the entire real numbers (at least to ±10<sup>300</sup>) without gaps.

By contrast, some `Fractional` types are not connected. In particular, `Rational` can *exactly* represent all its (rational-number) values, so each value is just an “infinitely small point”. You can never cover the entire real line with such points, and you can not compute functions like `sin` or `log` since the result of these functions is usually a non-rational real number.

---

It's worth pondering a bit what this “decent approximation” means. The Haskell standard doesn't define this. This story about every floating point number representing a whole interval of real numbers captures it quite well IMO. More generally, we might say: `Num`/`Fractional`/`Floating` are the classes of types that represent [equivalance classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of integer/rational/real numbers. In fact, these classes need not even be “small” intervals: in particular the finite types like `Word32` or the standard `Int` can be understood in a [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) sense, manifesting in results like `(2^70 :: Int) == 0`, i.e. the equivalence classes are then numbers spaces by a multiple of 2<sup>64</sup>.

In cases like `Integer` or `Rational`, the equivalence classes actually contain only a single element, i.e. the numbers are represented *exactly*. For real numbers, this is actually also possible, but much more tricky, it's called *exact real arithmetic*. There are libraries such as [aern](http://michalkonecny.github.io/aern/_site/index.html) that do this.

Comment: Isn't it a bit misleading to say "*`Fractional` types are not connected*" since the set of `Floating` types is a subset of `Fractional` types (since `class Fractional a => Floating a`)? It's like saying "things that carry DNA/RNA are living" and forgetting about viruses (that have RNA but no metabolism).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If a fractional type is floating, then it's connected, but if it's not connected, then it's not floating.

Comment: @JoshLee: Yeah, I know that: but I think the answer can be a bit confusing to that point...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I said _some_ `Fractional` types are not connected, and gave `Rational` as an example.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yeah for some reason the first time I looked I did not spotted the *some* :( Probably bit overworked because of the *Berlinade* deadline :)